# Print CSS File Not Changing Webpage

Tags: html, css

I have created a print css file to handle changes to my screen for when I print my webpage. Now I've coded my Print Css file so the header & navigation are not displayed, change all the fonts to Courier New, however for some reason my changes are being displayed. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link href="cpt330_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img src="newark.jpg" alt="picture of Newark">
</header>
<nav>
<ul><a href="homework.html">Home</a></ul>
<ul><a href="websites.html">Favorite Websites</a></ul>
<ul><a href="meals.html">Favorite Meals</a></ul>
</nav>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>



Print.CSS File
header, nav 
{
display: none;
}

html 
{
font-family: Courier New;
}

ul 
{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) at-rule in your print stylesheet to apply your CSS *only* if it's printing.

```css
@media print {
  header, nav {
    display: none;
  }

  html {
    font-family: Courier New;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```